# Understanding Socket paths with @ (Abstract Sockets)

Tags: java, android, sockets, unix, unix-socket

What is `@` in the socket path?

I am opening a unix socket using `LocalServerSocket()`.

```
root@device:/dev/socket # netstat -a
.......
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING      37305 @/storage/my_sock
unix  20     [ ]         DGRAM                      7231 /dev/socket/logdw
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING       7234 /dev/socket/logdr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING       7236 /dev/socket/logd
.......
```

Unlike for other sockets, my sockets is being prefixed with `@`. Also, I went and checked `/storage` partition. I could not find this socket generated there.

My code where I am creating the socket is shown below.

```
LocalServerSocket lss = new LocalServerSocket("/storage/my_sock");
LocalSocket sock = lss.accept();
InputStream ins = sock.getInputStream();
```

My idea is to open a local server socket from Java and use to as a communication channel to interact with a native C application. But As the path is invalid, I am not able to achieve this.

Comment: What kind of partition is /storage? Is it an external device or something?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206386/what-does-an-symbol-denotes-in-the-beginning-of-a-unix-domain-socket-path-in-l

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful It is a tmpfs partition present in Android systems..

Comment: @chrylis Thank you so much.. I understand it now. But am wondering is there a way to bypass it and create a normal socket or if I can use this abstract socket from my native application

Comment: @chrylis It seems that if the first byte is '\0' in the sun_path the socket is considered to be an abstract socket. I will try it. Thank you so much. The link you shared really helped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ in the unix socket paths indicate that they are **abstract sockets**. Abstact sockets cannot be seen physically on the disk. In android `LocalServerSocket()` creates abstract sockets.

### Android :

```
LocalServerSocket lss = new LocalServerSocket("my_sock");
LocalSocket sock = lss.accept();
InputStream ins = sock.getInputStream();
```

### Native :

From native application in order to open the same abstract socket, define `sun_path` as follows.

```
sock.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
sock.sun_path[0] = '\0'
strcpy(&sock.sun_path[1], "my_sock");
sock_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
len_addr = offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + strlen("my_sock") + 1;
res = connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sock, len_addr);
```

Note that the first byte of `sun_path` is '\0' and that the actual name continues from `&sun_path[1]`. By following this naming convention for naming the socket, the system identifies that we want to operate on an abstract socket and provides one for us.